# Simple mySQL Query Over Large Table Results in "MySQL server has gone away" Message

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm an applied statistician, unfamiliar with mySQL, and hoping for your advice.

**Error:** 
In running a relatively simple query (`SELECT MAX(Timestamp) FROM Database.Table;`) over a large mySQL table (a little over 2 billion rows), the server runs for about ten minutes and displays the error:

**Text of Error Message:**

In R:

```
08S01 2013 [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(a) Driver][mysqld-5.5.32-31.0]Lost connection to MySQL server during query
[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT MAX(Timestamp) FROM Database.Table;'
```

In mySQL Workbench:

```
Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query  
Duration: 600.495 sec
```

---

**Possible Lead:**
While monitoring the server status, the query appears to 'give up' and return the error when the InnoDB Buffer Usage reaches 100%. However the innodb_buffer_pool_size is already set to its maximum (about 76 GB). I get the same result doing just about anything with this particular table (querying min, trying to add an index, etc.).

I've gotten this result running the query via RStudioServer (probably not a good idea in the first place) and via mySQL Workbench. I am able to run the query without issue on smaller database tables (about 700 million rows and others smaller) of identical structure.

It's a little confusing as to why this error should occur, since a query like Find Max shouldn't be loading much data into memory at all - it should just run a comparison through all values in the TimeStamp col of Database.Table, keeping and returning the max value, and return it.

Comment: I thing that the use of ODBC may be an issue...are you able to run your query directly on the Mysql Server ?

Comment: Maybe you should try to deal with parameters "wait_timeout" and "max_allowed_packet" on mysql server side

Comment: @user2196728, I will test this out. I get the same error using MySQL Workbench, which I don't think relies on that ODBC Driver.

Comment: There are specific issue about your error regarding MySQL Workbench. I would try real SQL at server side, avoiding the use oh third party software

Comment: Again, thank you @user2196728 for your advice. I have increased both "wait_timeout" and "max_allowed_packet", but got the same error. I should note that in both runs, after exactly 600 seconds (600.495) the database timed out. Can you, by chance, think of a setting that might be 600 seconds and cause this error?

Comment: try this : http://www.hassmann-software.de/mysql-workbench-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-after-600-seconds/

Comment: user2196728 thank you again. We logged into the server and MySQL and ran the same query there, with the same result (Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query). I'm resetting MySQL Workbench and will retry there as well. Again, thanks for your advice.

Comment: I don't know how you have setup previous parameters, but you can deal with this one too : "net_read_timeout"

Comment: Well - in MySQL Workbench, changing the settings suggested in  hassmann-software.de?... resulted in the same error, but now after 1135 seconds. I really think the issue has something to do with the InnoDB Buffer Usage since that fills up when I get the error. --But thanks for all your help.

Comment: if you think about an innodb issue, you can try to deal with this param (yes, another one) : "innodb_buffer_pool_size"

Comment: I just come to news. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Re: @user2196728 yesterday: Not yet. I have run code of "SELECT * From DB.Table LIMIT X,10". When X < 900,000,000 it works fine. With X > 900,000,000 we get the same error. Thus We are likely to just split the 2Bill row table into three or more.

Comment: I'm at a uni, so we're planning to hire on help to sort this out and I'll post the solution we end up with. Thanks for all your help kind sir-or-madame!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised, nobody asked... do you even have an index on the timestamp column being queried?  It should be virtually instantaneous... but don't just build an index for the index, indexes should be based on more common querying criteria, but if stats based, and you are doing this and other queries based on when things have happened, an index would definitely help.  Also, how large are the rows of data, what other columns might there be that you might be running queries on... it may help significantly to build compound indexes (multiple field index) to help

Comment: I desire an index on this column, and the first thing I tried to run was to add just such an index. But got the same error. Thus, I then tried a simple query to see if I could get it to even run that, to no avail. After following user2196728's excellent (but thus far unsuccessful) advice, I really think the issue has something to do with my InnoDB Buffer filling up. (which is odd considering this query should use much memory at all).

Comment: Oh, there are over 2 billions rows. I'd like to add a Foreign Key to one other column, after I get the simple queries to run. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: It seems that issues related to this error message never deal with Index. But sure, indexes cannot be bad generally ;)

Answer (score 1):

Semi Solution (or, how I solved it)

Everyone's advice was prettimuch spot on.

The column over which I was running a query was not indexed. With so many rows (billions), even a fast machine will take a day or two to run a simple query. Adding an index to this column (which took ten hours) now means query times take seconds or fractions of a second.

Keys mySQL variables to adjust: `wait_timeout`, `max_allowed_packet` to resolve the "MySQL server has gone away” Message.

My issues with `innodb_buffer_pool_size` seem to have been a phantom, unrelated to my main issue.

Thank you for all your help user2196728 and DRapp